# Universal method with lambda’s criteria at Business Objects Collection

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, lambda, business-objects

I have abstract class for each Business Object in my app (**BO**)
Also have parent (generic) collection to store all BOs (named **BOC** - Business Object Collection)

What I would like to archive is created universal method iniside BOC similar to:

```
public  T GetBusinessObject (lambda_criteria)
```

So I could call this method similar to:

```
Employee emp = BOC.GetBusinessObject( Employee.ID=123 )
```

And method shall return BO meet to specified lambda criteria

Any tips how to archive that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your BOC inherits from or uses a generic list internally it's not too hard:

```
T GetBusinesObject<T>( Func<T, bool> predicate )
{
    return this.FirstOrDefault( predicate );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it would be a generic method - and if it is, surely you'd want an `OfType` / `GetTable` / something? Perhaps lose the `<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
T GetBusinessObject<T>(Predicate<T> constraint) where T : BO
```

and then called like

```
GetBusinessObject<Employee>( e => e.ID = 123 )
```

perhaps?

Comment: Thanks. But how it will be the body of proposed method?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a generic collection, then the caller should **already** (via LINQ) be able to use:

```
BOC<Employee> boc = ...
// checks exactly 1 match, throws if no match
var emp = boc.Single(e => e.ID = 123);
// checks at most 1 match, null if no match
var emp = boc.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ID = 123);
// checks at least one match, throws if no match
var emp = boc.First(e => e.ID = 123);
// returns first match, null if no match
var emp = boc.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID = 123);
```

that do?